# Shared Preferences not saved or recovered after setup in Settings Activity

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences, settings

I have done a basic Settings Activity.  What I want, is when user selects a option from a list (in Settings), this will save the value, and a "flag".

With this flag I want to use it in the Main Activity, to force an api call.

The problem is that the values in Shared Preferences are not "working" properly...

Here is how I set up the settings activity:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatPreferenceActivity {


        private static Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener = new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object value) {
                String stringValue = value.toString();

                if (preference instanceof ListPreference) {
                    // For list preferences, look up the correct display value in
                    // the preference's 'entries' list.
                    ListPreference listPreference = (ListPreference) preference;
                    int index = listPreference.findIndexOfValue(stringValue);

                    // Set the summary to reflect the new value.
                    preference.setSummary(
                            index >= 0
                                    ? listPreference.getEntries()[index]
                                    : null);

                    PreferenceManager
                            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(preference.getContext())
                            .edit()
                            .putBoolean("reload_data", true).commit();

                } else {
                    // For all other preferences, set the summary to the value's
                    // simple string representation.
                    preference.setSummary(stringValue);
                }
                return true;
            }
        };


        private static boolean isXLargeTablet(Context context) {
            return (context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout
                    & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE;
        }


        private static void bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(Preference preference) {
            // Set the listener to watch for value changes.
            preference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener);

            // Trigger the listener immediately with the preference's
            // current value.
            sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener.onPreferenceChange(preference,
                    PreferenceManager
                            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(preference.getContext())
                            .getString(preference.getKey(), ""));
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setupActionBar();
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_general);
        }

        /**
         * Set up the {@link android.app.ActionBar}, if the API is available.
         */
        private void setupActionBar() {
            ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
            if (actionBar != null) {
                // Show the Up button in the action bar.
                actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == android.R.id.home) {
                if (!super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item)) {
                    NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
                }
                return true;
            }
            return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
        }

        /**
         * {@inheritDoc}
         */
        @Override
        public boolean onIsMultiPane() {
            return isXLargeTablet(this);
        }

        /**
         * This method stops fragment injection in malicious applications.
         * Make sure to deny any unknown fragments here.
         */
        protected boolean isValidFragment(String fragmentName) {
            return SettingsFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName);
        }

        public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_general);
                setHasOptionsMenu(true);
                bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference(getString(R.string.languages_preferences_title)));
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                int id = item.getItemId();
                if (id == android.R.id.home) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), SettingsActivity.class));
                    return true;
                }
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Notice that I put the shared preference to save the flag as:

```
PreferenceManager
.getDefaultSharedPreferences(preference.getContext())
.edit()
.putBoolean("reload_data", true).commit();
```

And here is how I'm reading in MainActivity

```
 @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        boolean reloadData = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext())
                .getBoolean("reload_data", true);

        if (reloadData && presenter != null) {
            if (this.dailiesMap != null) {
                this.dailiesMap.clear();
            }
            presenter.getDailiesAchievementModels();
            PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext())
                    .edit()
                    .putBoolean("reload_data", false).apply();
        }
        super.onResume();
    }
```

When user it comes from Settings is suposed to be a true if user selects some option from the list. But this is not working. it comes to false.

First image is before change language(preference option)
Second image is after change language

[image]
[image]

As you can see , language change but not "my custom" key

Comment: How are you reading that in your MainActivity? Also, you should be using `apply()`.

Comment: @TheWanderer added how I'm reading the SP. (Thought I put it before...). Yes algo tested with apply(), but didn't worked. Was testing another way

Comment: And what exactly isn't working?

Comment: @TheWanderer When user it comes from Settings is suposed to be a true if user selects some option from the list. But this is not working. it comes to false.

Comment: Use `this` instead of `getBaseContext()`.

Comment: not working. :/

Comment: You should also be using `getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences()` in your SettingsActivity. There's no reason for your click listener to be static. Nor the helper methods that Android generated. Try broadcasting an intent instead of using preferences.

Comment: Did you debug that your `putBoolean("reload_data", true)` method was ever called?